# Why is the size of a template 1 Byte in C++?

Tags: c++, templates, instantiation

With `using`, an alias for a type can be defined and a unit of this type has the same size like an original instantation (1). A template however only weights 1 byte (2).

```
using aliasOfInt = int;

template<typename T>
struct intWrapper {
    using wrappedAliasOfInt = T;
};


int main() {
    // (1) --> 4B
    std::cout << "sizeof(aliasOfInt)      = " << sizeof(aliasOfInt) << std::endl;

    // (2) --> 1B
    std::cout << "sizeof(intAliasWrapper) = " << sizeof(intWrapper<int>) << std::endl;
}
```

In (2), is there a real type compiled or why is this only 1B?

http://cpp.sh/3eiry

Comment: Make it an regular struct and you'd get the same result.

Comment: How big do you expect your template to be, and why exactly? Just because I declare a `typedef` or a `using` as part of my class doesn't make it any bigger. Did you know that you could add a few million `typedef`s and `using`s to any class in C++, and its `sizeof` does not change? Why should it change? C++ does not work this way. It's not like it's adding any actual data that takes up any actual memory to store it, as part of the class or or struct.

Comment: What data members does `intWrapper` contain that would change its size?

Comment: A `using` type defined inside a class/struct doesn't occupy size in an object of that class/struct.

Comment: I was under the impression that by specialising the template in `main` with `intWrapper<int>`, I'd be creating a real class.

Comment: I don't understand why you think a "real class" object can't occupy one byte. It has no instance data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The template is a red herring. It's a structure without data members, regardless of `T`. Since C++ does not allow `sizeof(anything)==0`, `sizeof(intWrapper<int>)` has to be greater than 0. This leaves size 1 as a natural choice.